# Valgrind Invalid read of size 4, but not out-of-bounds nor not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

Tags: valgrind

I got many 'Invalid read of size N' while running my program written in C++ with Valgrind-3.11.0 on Ubuntu 64-bit.

The error messages are like following with different N where N is varying among 1, 4, 8.

```
Invalid read of size N.
Address 0xblahblah is 88 bytes inside a block of size 176 alloc'd
```

The block of size 176 is a C++ class object allocated with new operator and the size of N is small enough so that it's not out-of-bounds case.
Then why the Valgrind doesn't tell me the reason like 'not stacked', 'not malloced', 'recently freed'?

Does anyone know why Valgrind decided this as an invalid read when there are no messages like 'not stacked', 'not malloced', 'recently freed'?

Comment: "The size of N is small enough it's not out-of-bounds case." Non-sequitur. The size of N is usually a power of 2 up to your register size. Has nothing to do with whether the access is out of bounds.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks for your comment, but I don't understand your point. When N is 8, 88 + 8 is still inside the block of 176 bytes allocated, so I decided that Valgrind didn't report this as an error because of out-of-bounds access.

Comment: Oh, okay. It is N combined with the offset that is not out of range. You tried to blame N so I didn't look at the other parts. Perhaps it is reporting an alignment error? (Reading further, N is at most 48, which doesn't match the alignment theory.)

Answer (score 0):

N corresponds to the size of the underlying primitive data type. Roughly speaking, 1 would be a char or a bool, 4 would be and int or float and 8 would be a long int, double or pointer.

```
XX bytes inside a block of size YY alloc'd
```

First of all this means that the memory is dynamic (~on the heap) rather than automatic (~on the stack). Secondly, you know the size of the object(s) allocated. If you know the size per object (you can use sizeof to get that), then you can work out how many objects were allocated.

Are there any other serious errors before this?

Do you use any Valgrind client requests in your code?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't use Valgrind client request. For 'serious errors' you mentioned it's a bit complicated to answer, because I'm working with other colleagues. One of my colleague says that there were 'Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s)' before the 'Invalid read' which I had never seen. Anyway after removing the 'uninitialized value access error' there seems no more 'Invalid read'. However, I still don't understand how this can lead to 'Invalid read' without exact reason of invalidness like 'not stacked', 'not malloced', 'recently freed'.